# How to hide fragment in Relativelayout and show another on in it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, fragment

ask for helping to do these steps please:
I have on main activity has one Relative layout

```
     <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_framelayout_small_contain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

1.when activity starts it replaces RelativeLayout with fragment (f1)

2.(f1) has listview when user click I have to show another fragment (f2)
in f1 place so I use these method in MainActivity

```
public void set_fragment_subject(String path)
{
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft=  fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    Fragment_subjects f1 = new Fragment_subjects(path);
    Fragment_season f2 = new Fragment_season();
    ft.add(R.id.main_framelayout_small_contain,f1);
    ft.hide(f2);
    ft.commit();
}
```

may it looks strange but I do this after search because I want to retain f1's data when press backbutton.

The problem appears When user clicks in f1 , Activity shows f2 but over the f1.

Sorry to take long time ,Any one can help to do what I want correctly,Thanks

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to replace f1 with f2 and not add f2 over f1?

Comment: Yes but keep f1 data hidden to show later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello @Ghadeer here you can access fragment as tow way one was the normal replace old fragment and another is maintain back stack, But I think you have need tow second way because you want to first fragment data as, so follow the following step for do it,

Please take frame layout instead of Relative layout

```
<FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/main_framelayout_small_contain"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>
```

Here I have created tow method we will use in our code so put in your activity where you start your fragment :

```
public void setFragment(Fragment fragment, int container) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(container, fragment).addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getName()).commit();
    }

    public void popAllFragments() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    }
```

Please add following code when you start first fragment :

```
popAllFragments();
Fragment_subjects f1 =new Fragment_subjects();
setFragment(f1,R.id.main_framelayout_small_contain);
```

And add following code when you start second framgnet :

```
Fragment_season f2 =new Fragment_season();
 setFragment(f1,R.id.main_framelayout_small_contain);
```

Then after finally  on your back button write following code :

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    getActivity().onBackPressed();
```

Try this may be work for you

Comment: Thanks a lot really, I try it but I think after popallfragments we add two fragments to stack so the problem still the two fragments appear over each other again.another thing I don't understand what and where last code for back button work.Sorry but can explain?

Comment: If you have not started any fragment before one then you no need to define  popAllFragments(); and for the last one you can also this code in your onBackpress() of your activity,  getActivity().onBackPressed();  this will pop one by one your fragment from stack.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the current fragment with a new fragment.
This can be done by following code.

```
Fragment fragmentSeason = new Fragment_season();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack if needed
transaction.replace(R.id.main_framelayout_small_contain, fragmentSeason);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

On back press, you would get your first fragment.

Comment: Thanks but f1 data will lose when using replace so I think about hide to show f1 and its data later

Comment: Hi @ghadeerdarwesh , addToBackStack would do your job. This code would replace your first fragment and when you would press back button, you would get your first fragment back.

Comment: HI,I mean data in listview that fragments contains will be lost

Comment: @ghadeerdarwesh Have you tried that? I don't think it would get lost.

Answer (score 0):

There is some implementations issue in method set_fragment_subject

If you have declare set_fragment_subject  method in Fragment_1 then your code in method should be like this,

```
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft=  fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    final Fragment_season f2 = new Fragment_season();

    ft.add(R.id.main_framelayout_small_contain,f2);

    ft.hide(this);// Here this means the current fragment because this method is declared in Fragment_1
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
```